# Making render method virtual?

Tags: c++

I'm starting with C++ in more depth while building a simple 2d game engine. In my engine I have (or want to have) an "Abstract" `GameEntity` class, which carries the methods `draw`, `update`, and maybe `position` (x, y). I will add more stuff while it occurs to me.

Classes to inherit from `GameEntity` would be anything that could be drawn on screen (`ParticleSystem`, `MovingSprite`, `StaticSprite`, `GuiMenu`, etc...)

My problem is that to achieve that, I have declared `GameEntity` `draw()` and `update()` methods virtual:

```
virtual draw()=0;
virtual update()=0;
```

So `ParticleSystem` has it's own draw and `MovingSprite` also has it's own `draw()` (and `update()`).

I know virtual functions are expensive, or at least more expensive than regular methods. Do you think that what I'm doing is awful? Or too bad? If you do, I would really appreciate a better way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you noticed a slow down in your code? I doubt it. Good design > micro-optimization.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I guess I wasn't doing it that bad at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't bad; the overhead isn't *that* significant (you might consult [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667634/what-is-the-performance-cost-of-having-a-virtual-method-in-a-c-class/667680#667680)).

This is, for example, the general approach taken by [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg), an open source scene graph based on OpenGL.  OSG has [a `Node` class](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/browser/OpenSceneGraph/trunk/include/osg/Node), from which all node types used in the scene graph are derived, and it uses a plethora of virtual functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I happen to be using a SceneGraph for my game too, but it's a bit more simple and I only allow lists of subNodes in the scenes for now (don't need to support a tree structure of sub-nodes yet ).

Answer (score 2):

The system I work on now uses virtual draw() and update() in the 3d layer tree; our performance bottlenecks are not in the virtual dispatch.  I think your design is fine to start with; you can profile later if you think it's really bad.  It's, what, a load and a jump?

Answer (score 2):

Calling a virtual functions costs usually two pointer indirection more than a normal function call, so that's a really small overhead that should nearly never matter.

Also objects containing functions are the size of one pointer larger than objects without any virtual functions (they contain a pointer to the objects virtual function table). But if you don't plan on having really excessive amounts of small objects that also shouldn't matter.

For more details also see the [C++ FAQ lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.4).

And to answer your question: I think it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to handle multiple cases at runtime (and I think you do, in this case), it is best to use virtual functions. The compiler can probably optimize it as well or even better than an `if-else` statement, since virtual functions are something like a special case of `if-else`.