# making a function virtual and the changes to code it requires

Tags: c++

I am trying to comprehend virtual functions. How so I make my put() function virtual? What changes does that necessitate in the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Circle
{
public:
    Circle(double radius) {this->radius = radius; }
    void put() const {cout << "Radius = " << radius;}
private:
    double radius;
};

class ColoredCircle: public Circle
{
public:
    ColoredCircle(double radius, string color);
    void put() const;
private:
    string color;
};

ColoredCircle::ColoredCircle(double radius, string color)
    : Circle(radius), color(color) {}

void ColoredCircle::put() const
{
    Circle::put();
    cout << " Color = " << color;
}

int main()
{
    ColoredCircle redCircle(100., "red");
    Circle* circle1 = &redCircle;
    circle1->put();
    cout << endl;
    Circle circle(50.);
    Circle* circle2 = &circle;
    circle2->put();
    cout << endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what virtual functions are and why one would need them? If not, start by reading a good textbook on C++.

Comment: Does whatever resource you are using to learn C++ not have a section on virtual functions? Or do you have a specific question about this?

Comment: How do you make the put() function virtual?

Comment: Write `virtual` in front of it in the base-class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to write the `virtual` keyword in front of the function in the base class :

```
class Circle
{
public:
    Circle(double radius) {this->radius = radius; }
    virtual void put() const {cout << "Radius = " << radius;}
//  ^^^^^^^
private:
    double radius;
};
```

But you should understand the case where the `virtual` functions are used. What is the performances cost, why it is useful, etc ...

*A little piece of answer :* A `virtual method` is a special of `method` whose the behavior can be overriden within an inheriting `class` with a`method` of the same signature.

*About the performance cost :* There is definitely measurable overhead when calling a virtual function - the call must use the *vtable* to resolve the address of the function for that type of object. The extra instructions are the least of your worries. Not only do vtables prevent many potential compiler optimizations, they can also thrash your *I-Cache*.

Of course whether these penalties are significant or not depends on your application, how often those code paths are executed, and your inheritance patterns.

I would suggest you to read some articles about virtual functions, here is a non exhaustive list :

- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function
- http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/122-virtual-functions/
- [What is the performance cost of having a virtual method in a C++ class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667634/what-is-the-performance-cost-of-having-a-virtual-method-in-a-c-class)