# C++ Instantiating childs of an abstract class with pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, return-by-value

I have an abstract class, let it be for example **Animal**. An Animal has a pure virtual function *eat*, which every animal must implement if they don't want to starve. I ensure that only a child of an Animal can be instantiated by this way:

Animal.hpp

```
class Animal
{

public:

    enum eAnimal{
        CAT=0,
        DOG=1,
        BIRD=2
    };

    // Instantiates the desired animal.
    static Animal GetAnimal(const int animal);

    virtual void Eat() const = 0;

protected:

    Animal();
};
```

Animal.cpp

```
Animal Animal::GetAnimal(const int animal)
{
    switch(animal)
    {
    case CAT:
        return Cat();
    case DOG:
        return Dog();
    case BIRD:
        return Bird();
    default:
        cerr << "Animal not recognized." << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
}

Animal::Animal()
{}
```

With this, a **Cat** would be:

Cat.hpp

```
class Cat : public Animal
{

public:

    Cat();

    void Eat() const;
};
```

Cat.cpp

```
Cat::Cat() : Animal()
{}

void Cat::Eat() const
{
    // The cat eats.
}
```

However this code doesn't work, it gets an error *invalid abstract return type 'Animal'* in *GetAnimal*, because Animal is abstract and can't be instantiated, altough my API ensures it won't.

Which smart solutions may this problem have? I can do the function *Eat* not pure and give it a default implementation, but I'd like not to do it.

Comment: @Galik Some Cameras are Animals.

Comment: Virtual member functions works with pointers

Comment: Are you sure you need run-time polymorphism here in the first place?

Comment: @SergeyA what do you suggest?

Comment: @SantiagoGil, what are you trying to do? :)

Comment: @SergeyA following the example, my system is called with an animal type (an integer is passed by parameter), and I must work only with this animal type in all the system lifelong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Animal Animal::GetAnimal(const int animal)
{
    switch(animal)
    {
    case CAT:
        return Cat();
    case DOG:
        return Dog();
    case BIRD:
        return Bird();
    default:
        cerr << "Animal not recognized." << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

You say that `GetAnimal` should return an `Animal` **object**, this is not how inheritance works, inheritance works mainly through pointers. When you try to return an object of a type the compiler implicitly has to create an `Animal` object, but it's not allowed to because `Animal` is an abstract class. Even if you were to make `eat()` only `virtual` you'd still have the [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) problem.

You can make it return a `Animal*` and free the result after you used it:

```
Animal* Animal::GetAnimal(const int animal)
{
    switch(animal)
    {
    case CAT:
        return new Cat();
    case DOG:
        return new Dog();
    case BIRD:
        return new Bird();
    default:
        cerr << "Animal not recognized." << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Caller:

```
Dog* myDog = GetAnimal(DOG);

//somewhere later when you dont need myDog anymore..(don't forget this!)
delete myDog;
```

But if you have access to C++11 or later I recommend using smart pointers instead of raw pointers to let the pointer free itself:

```
#include <memory>
std::unique_ptr<Animal> Animal::GetAnimal(const int animal)
{
    switch(animal)
    {
    case CAT:
        return std::make_unique<Cat>();
    case DOG:
        return std::make_unique<Dog>();
    case BIRD:
        return std::make_unique<Bird>();
    default:
        cerr << "Animal not recognized." << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Caller:

```
auto dog = GetAnimal(DOG);
//no explicit delete required.
```

Answer (score 1):

You want your return type of GetAnimal to be a pointer to an Animal rather than an Animal itself. In general, whenever you are trying to use polymorphism, pointers are the way to go.

My best guess is that this is what is happening: You are instantiating a Cat. Then in your return statement, since you aren't returning a pointer, it must make a copy of your data. Since the return type is Animal, it attempts to invoke the default Animal copy constructor. Therefore, it is trying to instantiate an Animal class, which of course cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual member functions works with pointers. Just change a bit your API, to something like that:

```
std::unique_ptr<Animal> Animal::GetAnimal(const int animal)
{
    switch(animal)
    {
    case CAT:
        return std::make_unique<Cat>();
    (...)
    }
}
```

Note that I'm assuming you are using, at least, C++14

Comment: @curiousguy dynamic inherintance, that is implemented with virtual functions works with pointer, exactly as OP ask

Comment: Virtual functions work normally on an automatic object; of course, the dynamic type is known at compiler, but they "work". If you need to choose the type of an object at runtime, of course you need dynamic allocation.

Comment: I understand fully well the OP, and the answer. Virtual functions are *not* the problem here. When you return by value, you create another instance. This is the issue: that instance has different type. And here, it's an abstract class so you can't even create it. The problem is the creation of a distinct instance of a distinct type.

Comment: @curiousguy What is the purpose of virtual function if not to access derived function from its base class? Virtual functions has runtime overhead, so you only declare a function virtual if you want to access it via its base class, and this access is done via pointers (runtime polymorphism). Can you declare all functions virtual? Yes, you can, but should you? So, what is wrong with the answer? It creates a derived object that can be accessed via base object. That the purpose of virtual functions. Thats how you use virtual functions. Via pointers.

Comment: A virtual call is dispatched based on the dynamic type; the purpose of virtual function is the support of virtual dispatch. Virtual function calls only have overhead when the dynamic type is not known at compile time; for automatic objects, there is no overhead. You probably should not declare all functions virtual; you should not declare any virtual function if you have no specified the requirements on the overrider, something which most people don't pay attention to.

Comment: Congrats, you are saying **almost** what I've said before, just in other words. But, you need to read more about [virtual functions overhead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667634/what-is-the-performance-cost-of-having-a-virtual-method-in-a-c-class). To me, this is the end of this discussion.

Comment: "_Congrats, you are saying almost what I've said before_" No "_Can you declare all functions virtual? Yes, you can"_ No, you cannot. Non trivial program will fail to compile or compile but fail to work properly.